# How to create a seed command to clear data rows from table using Flask CLI and Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, flask, command-line-interface, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a seed command which allows me to clear all data from any table that I choose. Whenever I type the command, it shows this error:

[image: Error stack]

This is the command I use base on the way I set up the seed command "flask seed clear <table_name>". And this is what my code looks like:

```
from flask.cli import AppGroup
from .seeder import create_roles, create_users
from .database import db
import click

seed_cli = AppGroup("seed", help="Various database seed commands.")

# Seed roles
@seed_cli.command("roles")
def seed_roles():
    create_roles()
    print("[+] Roles has been seeded successfully!") # Works

# Seed users
@seed_cli.command("users")
def seed_users():
    create_users()
    print("[+] Users has been seed successfully!") # Works

# Seed command to clear data for chosen table
@seed_cli.command("clear")
@click.argument("table_name")
def delete_rows(table_name):
    db.session.query(table_name).delete()
    db.session.commit()
    print(f"[+] All data from {table_name} has been cleared!")
```

I've checked out this documentation on how to set up the code here: [Flask CLI documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/?highlight=click#application-context)
Is there anyway to achieve this action? Any help is appreciated.